# Dealing with multiple custom routes in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my Home controller set up like this, going into different functions depending on the parameters it recieves.
Problem is in my home controller, it treats "gametwo" as a query for my route on my home controller.

Example
mysite.com/serchsomething <-- This will search the given string
mysite.com/gametwo <-- This also searches instead of going to gametwo controller

I have normal routeconfig.cs file, with just added attributeroutes.

What is the best way of dealing with routes with multiple parameters? So that they wont be ambigious or crash with any other routes? thanks

**home controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{Query}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string Query)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{Query}/{Version}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string Query, int Version)
    {
        ...
    }
```

**GameTwo controller**

```
    [Route("GameTwo")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**routeconfig**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: You have to give your routes something to define and make them unique, e.g. `[Route("Search/{Query}")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this above

**Home Controller**

```
  [HttpGet]        
        public ActionResult serchsomething(string Query)
        {
//do something
        }
```

**Game Two Controller**

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Routing**

```
    public class RouteConfig
        {
            public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
            {
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        /*serchsomething  action*/
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "Your route name 1",
                    url: "serchsomething/{Query}",
                    defaults: new
                    {
                        controller = "home",
                        action = "serchsomething"
                    }
                 );

                /*GameTwo Controller*/
                routes.MapRoute(
                   name: "Your route name 2",
                   url: "GameTwo",
                   defaults: new
                   {
                       controller = "GameTwo",
                       action = "Index"
                   }
                );
    /* default*/
            routes.MapRoute(
                  name: "Default",
                  url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                  defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving correct controller name?. I am just seeing your url as

```
 mysite.com/gametwo

 but controller name as GameTwo  Pls change it as GameTwo and try again.
```